# youtube OAuth2.0 wrong redirect_uri

Tags: java, oauth, youtube

Google API ни в какую не хочет авторизовываться на Youtube. 
Ошибка следующая

400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Application: webcam

You can email the developer of this application at: whitesaint12@gmail.com

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8080/Callback did not match a registered redirect URI.

Learn more

Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю как у ютуба, но у гугла redirect uri должен совпадать в настройках приложения (те настройки что в настройках приложения на сайте), и в настройках вашего приложения который составляет запрос.
Совпадать должно всё, вплоть до порта.

Я составлял запрос вот так:

```
var uri = string.Format("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?{0}&{1}&{2}&{3}&{4}",
                "client_id=" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["google_client_id"],
                "response_type=code",
                "scope=openid%20email",
                "redirect_uri=" + RedirectUri,
                "state=" + state
                );
```

Comment: Ошибка чуть в другом была, но Ваш ответ тоже имеет вес)